# access database table values and use them as a parameters to stored procedures in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-table

I have one specification database table, and now i have to take one value from that table and pass that value as parameter to stored procedure.

that value is taken based on condition like

```
select spec_value from spec_tab where spec_name=fcst_mdl_name;
```

and i have to take that spec value and pass that as param to stored procedure.

i used set and select functions but with them i'm not able to reach my objective.

can anyone help to tackle this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assign spec_value in a user defined during select query and then call SP just like below.

```
set @specValue := null;
select @specValue := spec_value from spec_tab where spec_name=fcst_mdl_name;
call sp_Name(@specValue);
```